# Switch ContentPresenter of ListBoxItem Based on Selection

Tags: wpf, listbox, controltemplate, listboxitem

I am trying to switch out the ContentPresenter of a ListBoxItem when it is selected, while using multiple DataTemplates to represent different types of data.

Here is the UserControl that defines the ListBox inside:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Homage.View.FilePanelView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:Homage.View"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Homage.ViewModel"
         xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:Homage.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SlugViewModel}">
        <vw:SlugView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HeaderSlugViewModel}">
        <vw:HeaderSlugView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ContentSlugViewModel}">
        <vw:ContentSlugView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border Name="SlugContainer" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" Padding="5">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="SlugContainer" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Slugs}" Padding="5" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Based on the type of data to be shown (e.g., a "Header Slug") a certain DataTemplate is applied to the ListBoxItem.  This is working great, but I am wanting to adjust the DataTemplate of the selected ListBoxItem to a different DataTemplate -- again, based on the data type being shown.

The goal is that, because each data type is different, each would have a unique look when not selected and would receive a unique set of options when selected.

If I can get the above to work, that would be great!  But, I also want to complicate things...

While each data type has unique controls they also have common controls.  So I would ideally like to define all the common controls once so that they appear in the same place in the ListBox.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommonSelectedTemplate">
    <!-- common controls -->
    ...
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UniqueSelectedTemplate">
        <!-- all the unique controls -->
        <ContentPresenter /> 
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- more common controls -->
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

If I have to define all the common stuff multiple times (for now) I'll live. =)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759390/wpf-listbox-templating-how-to-create-a-common-template-but-still-change-content/5759656#5759656) might help out with your second problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer H.B.  My current setup actually lets me have a "common" and "unique" part, but I'm trying to make it continue to hold true for a solution to the first issue.  I've seen a few examples on setting the look based on IsSelected, but nothing so far that seems to offer a nested structure of common and unique elements.

Comment: You can use the DataTemplateSelector class. But in this case you should add the IsSelected property to each item class and add keys to all implicit data templates. About common controls, thay can be replaced by a UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that we have only two data types: `Item1ViewModel` and `Item2ViewModel`. Therefore we need 4 data templates: 2 for the common state, 2 for the selected state.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1" DataType="local:Item1ViewModel">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" Foreground="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2" DataType="local:Item2ViewModel">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2}" Foreground="Blue" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1Selected" DataType="local:Item1ViewModel">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2Selected" DataType="local:Item2ViewModel">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2}" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Blue" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

For switching the content between two templates based on different types I use the `DataTemplateSelector` class:

```
public class SampleTemplateSelector:DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Type1Template { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Type2Template { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is Item1ViewModel)
            return Type1Template;
        else if (item is Item2ViewModel)
            return Type2Template;

        return null;
    }
}
```

We need two instances of this selector: one for the common state and one for the selected state.

```
    <local:SampleTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector" 
                                  Type1Template="{StaticResource Template1}"
                                  Type2Template="{StaticResource Template2}"/>
    <local:SampleTemplateSelector x:Key="selectedTemplateSelector" 
                                  Type1Template="{StaticResource Template1Selected}"
                                  Type2Template="{StaticResource Template2Selected}"/>
```

And after that you should add this code which switches two selectors:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
        <ContentControl x:Name="content"  Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="content" Property="ContentTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource selectedTemplateSelector}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

That's all, apply this `ItemTemplate` to your `ListBox` without changing the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" />
```